# Get number from span which is inside span with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So I have this piece from html

```
<label for="productX" id="_productX_label">
   <span class="t">XS</span>
   <span class="s">10 x 10 cm</span>
   <span class="p"> <span>5 300</span> Ft </span>
</label>
```

And I want to get that '5 300' out of it.

My code to get that:

```
print(item.find('label',{'for':'productX'}).find('span', attrs={'class': 'p'}).find('span'))
```

but it only prints out this:

```
<span></span>
```

I hope somebody can help

Edit: already tried to write .text to the end but it gives nothing ' '.

Comment: Add a .text to your last .find('span') so it says .find('span').text

Comment: `.text` seems to work for the example you posted. Perhaps this is related to the site? Can you post URL?

Comment: yeah [link](http://www.netprinter.hu/termekek/vaszonkep)

Comment: strangely the  `5 300` isn't downloaded from the webpage when you get the page with `python requests`. There is a decent chance that some js script or other is filling it out after

Comment: We cannot reproduce the problem as the problem is not with the bs4 scraping, but with the getting the page source of the web page (content is loaded dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, you just need to add `.text` to the last `find` function.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<label for="productX" id="_productX_label">
<span class="t">XS</span>
<span class="s">10 x 10 cm</span>
<span class="p"> <span>5 300</span> Ft </span>
</label>"""

item = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print(item.find('label',{'for':'productX'}).find('span', attrs={'class': 'p'}).find('span').text)
```

Outputs:

```
5 300
```

Comment: Already tried but it gives me nothing. Also tried .get_text() but same result

Comment: Maybe the content is being rendered via javascript, thus you cannot access it via the requests module, that I assume you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = """
<label for="productX" id="_productX_label">
  <span class="t">XS</span>
  <span class="s">10 x 10 cm</span>
  <span class="p"> <span>5 300</span> Ft </span>
</label>
"""
final_result = re.sub('^\s+|[a-zA-Z\s]+$', '', soup(s, 'lxml').find('span', {'class':'p'}).text)
```

Output:

```
u'5 300'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with select, which doesn't give you as many options but is quite readable

```
import bs4

s = """<label for="productX" id="_productX_label">
   <span class="t">XS</span>
   <span class="s">10 x 10 cm</span>
   <span class="p"> <span>5 300</span> Ft </span>
</label>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')

soup.select_one("#_productX_label > span > span").text
```

Output: `'5 300'`

---

For your other issue of not being able to use the text property, perhaps the data is being filled out by a js function, or stored in an attribute?